# error in count script for number of occurences

Tags: shell-script, logs

I have written a small script to count number of occurrences of logs in a particular file. The following is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=1
while read line
do
    found=$( grep M $line )
    OCCURENCE=$( grep M /log.txt)
    if [ "$OCCURENCE" ]; then
        echo $count")" $line >> filesave.txt
    fi
    count=$((count+1))
done < log1.txt
```

but I am getting this error:

```
./count.sh
./count.sh: syntax error at line 10: `found=$' unexpected
```

Comment: You seem to be using bash-specific constructs; what happens with `#! /bin/bash` at the top of your script?

Comment: thanks ,it ran the script ,but it still throws error like                                       "grep: can't open 1.8M"                                                                        "grep: can't open 1.4M"

Comment: delete the spaces between the brackets and quote the variable `line` in line 10: `found=$(grep M "$line")`

Comment: You may find the `-c`/ `--count` option of `grep` for printing a count of matching lines for each input file useful.

Comment: Please show some sample output and explain what you are trying achieve. As Sebastian posted the `-c` option of grep couldbe useful. Another option (since you seem to need the lines themselves is to simply use grep to get the lines into the output file and then `wc -l` to count them.

Comment: I'm closing this (for the moment) as there seem to be several items of data missing from the question, including what Unix is being used (to identify the possible cause of the syntax error, which may indicate a very old `sh` version on Solaris) and (if further help with solving the underlying task is wanted) what the input data looks like and what you want to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a bash warrior king but have your try this syntax at line 10 :

```
found=$( `grep M $line` )
```

Or some tweak around that as you try to call a program (grep) with its own options.

Comment: Why would they want to run the output of `grep`?

Comment: If somebody doesn't know POSIX shell syntax, both backticks `\`echo foo\`` and dollar+parenthesis `$(...)` *execute* the enclosed string as a command and collect the standard output. Writing `$(\`echo foo\`)` would execute the command `echo foo` first, take it's standard output and try to execute that. I personally try to avoid backticks because encoding requirements for `$(...)` syntax is nicer to use. I'd recommend deleting this answer or fixing it to provide better guidance.